# Preventing rest application to open new hibernate session per new request

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I have about 12-15 table entities.

These entities are tied by relation @oneToMany and @ManyToOne

A single unit of work , required all this entities to process a input.

There may be concurrent inputs , as the application exposed as rest api.

How do manage my hibernate sessions in best way such that hibernate session is not required to open everytime , eventually preventing database physical connections.

I am using hibernate 4.Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Opening a new session for each request is the normal thing to do. As long as they're closed at the end of the request, there shouldn't be any problem. If you're exhausting your pool of database connections, it just means you're not closing your sessions correctly and reliably.

Comment: this has to be taken care by the rest api i suppose hibernate is not suppose to handle api sessions

Comment: @JBNizet , i am going through a scenario like there are 40 requests , each opening a new session, database pool is of say about 50 .Now none of the request has reached to session.close , as the process is bit bulky. Now again 11 requests come opening a session , thereby reaching the connections to 51 , thereby exhausting the connection pool.

Comment: Then accept that the 51th request has to wait until one of the previous request ends, or increase the size of the pool if the database can support more than 50 connections, or make your code faster.

Comment: @RahulSingh Its about hibernate session

Comment: @JBNizet i have c3p0 configured to limit the connection , but still it seems to make more connections that the specified max size

Comment: Then either your diagnostic is wrong (most likely), or c3p0 has a bug.  What do you expect from us?